# Can't boot to system (lineageOS) after updating TWRP

Tags: twrp, unbricking, lineageos

I've been using lineageOS 14.1 for a long time on my Galaxy S4 mini (gt-i9195) and recently wanted to try some apps requiring root access.
In the developer options I could set root access only to "ADB only". I tried installing su from https://download.lineageos.org/extras via TWRP but the installation failed (probably because I tried installing the arm64 version instead of arm, I'm guessing retrospectively?).
Anyway, I decided to upgrade TWRP to 3.3.1-0 (from 3.0.1-0 before I think) following random advice I found online.
I started flashing 3.3.1-0 to the recovery partition via TWRP but it got stuck while "Patching system unconditionally".
After more than an hour of this I powered off and restarted into recovery mode.

Surprisingly, TWRP now boots as version 3.3.1-0 without any issues.
However, whenever I try to boot system into lineageOS I just get the Samsung startup logo and then the screen stays black.

Any idea how I might be able to start up lineageOS again?
I would try rolling back to an older version of TWRP maybe, but I couldn't yet figure out how to get the image file onto the phone.
I tried installing adb on my desktop and plugging the phone in via USB but `adb devices` does not find the phone.
Might Odin work for this despite not having the standard ROM and without wiping the phone?

Unfortunately I don't have a backup, as I didn't have the storage space for it.
But while there's nothing super important on the phone I would still of course prefer not having to wipe everything.

Comment: If your main LineageOS system partition does not boot I would try to re-flash that image instead of fiddling around with the recovery twrp (which should not affect the main OS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it without any data loss by putting a zip of the same LineageOS version I was using on a SD card and re-flashing with that from TWRP 3.3.1 (wiping only cache and Dalvik).

Thanks @Robert.

I still don't understand how exactly I screwed my system partition in the first place but I'm happy anyway.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on how did you re-flash without loosing data?
Did you do just this: "On the device, select “Apply Update”, then “Apply from ADB” to begin sideload..."

Comment: It's been a while but I'm relatively sure I just booted into TWRP, selected "Install" and then picked the lineageOS image I downloaded on the sd card to install from there.